# Invalidate metadata/refresh imapala from spark code

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, impala

I'm working on a NRT solution that requires me to frequently update the metadata on an Impala table.

Currently this invalidation is done after my spark code has run.
I would like to speed things up by doing this refresh/invalidate directly from my Spark code.

What would be the most efficient approach?

- Oozie is just too slow (30 sec overhead? no thanks)
- An SSH action to an (edge) node seems like a valid solution but feels "hackish"
- I don't see a way to do this from the hive context in Spark either.

Comment: About Spark `HiveContext` : it enables a job to interact with the Hive **Metastore**, in client/server mode. But it is completely unaware of what other jobs are doing against the Metastore at the same time -- i.e. other Spark jobs, Pig jobs, Impala queries, Hive CLI queries, HiveServer2 queries, Hue browsing sessions...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`REFRESH` and `INVALIDATE METADATA` commands are specific to Impala.
You must be connected to an Impala daemon to be able to run these -- which trigger a refresh of the Impala-specific metadata cache *(in your case you probably just need a `REFRESH` of the list of files in each partition, not a wholesale `INVALIDATE` to rebuild the list of all partitions and all their files from scratch)*

You could use the Spark `SqlContext` to connect to Impala via JDBC and *read* data -- but not *run* arbitrary commands. Damn. So you are back to the basics:

- download the latest [Cloudera JDBC driver for Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html)
- install it on the server where you run your Spark job
- list all the JARs in your `*.*.extraClassPath` properties
- develop some Scala code to open a JDBC session against an Impala daemon and run arbitrary commands (such as `REFRESH somedb.sometable`) -- the hard way

Hopefully Google will find some examples of JDBC/Scala code such as [this one](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch16s02.html)

Answer (score 1):

Seems this has been fixed by Impala 3.3.0 (cf. Section "Metadata Performance Improvements" [here](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_new_features.html)):

> Automatic invalidation of metadata
>
> With automatic metadata management enabled, you no longer have to issue INVALIDATE / REFRESH in a number of conditions.
>
> In Impala 3.3, the following additional event in Hive Metastore can trigger automatic INVALIDATE / REFRESH of Metadata:
>
> - INSERT into tables and partitions from Impala or from Spark on the same or multiple cluster configuration

Answer (score 0):

all the above steps are not required, you can write the below code and execute invalidate metadata query to impala table.

```
impala_node_ip_address = "XX.XX.XX.XX"
impala Query = "impala-shell -i "+"\"" + str(impala_node_ip_address) + "\"" + " -k -q " + "\""+"invalidate metadata DBNAME"+"." + "TableName" + "\""
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I would like to do I from my code, not as an external script. There is/was no other option than going the JDBC route.